# What's a more efficient way to create a field-less form without a dummy forms.Form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to implement a form that simply presents data, and offers the user the choice of "Accept" or "Deny". I'm sending the data that I want to display by overriding the `get_context_data()` method, and I have two `<input type="submit">`'s on the template.

Here is the view:

```
class FriendResponseView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    form_class = FriendResponseForm
    template_name = 'user_profile/friend_response.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FriendResponseView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['respond_to_user'] = self.kwargs.get('username')
        responding_profile = Profile.objects.get(
            user__username=self.request.user)
        requesting_profile = Profile.objects.get(
            user__username=self.kwargs['username'])

        friend_object = Friend.objects.get(requester=requesting_profile, accepter=responding_profile)
        context['accepter_asks'] = friend_object.requester_asks
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        super(PairResponseView, self).form_valid(form)
        if 'accept' in self.request.POST:
            # do something
        else:
            return redirect('/')
```

Because the form does not accept any input or choices, I have this dummy form:

```
class FriendResponseForm(forms.Form):
    pass
```

There must be a more efficient, Django way to achieve the same result. How would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is not to use a FormView at all, but a basic TemplateView. Then define `post` to do the submit logic.

```
class FriendResponseView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'user_profile/friend_response.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ...

    def post(self, request):
        if 'accept' in self.request.POST:
            # do something
        else:
            return redirect('/')
```